# Ошибка при composer install Executing script cache:clear [KO] [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error code 255

Tags: php, веб-программирование, symfony, composer, backend

При попытке выполнить команду: 
`composer install` получаю ряд ошибок: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее по рекомендации выполняю команду `composer update` после чего идет установка, но под конец получаю на выходе: `executing script cache:clear [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error code 255`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот проект уже установлен на другом пк, и работает стабильно. Но при попытке установить у себя столкнулся с такими проблемами. Также искал в чем может быть причина `executing script cache:clear [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error code 255` на некоторых форумах писали уже о такой проблеме [источник](https://coderoad.ru/54851783/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-cache-clear-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-255), но в моем случае без результатов. Заранее благодарю за любые подсказки как решить данную проблему.

Содержимое Kernel.php

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use RDV\SymfonyContainerMocks\DependencyInjection\TestKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    public function getProjectDir(): string
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__);
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php'));
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes): void
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
}
```

Comment: У композера есть post-update/post-install хуки, которые запускаются после этих команд. У вас не установились все зависимости, как показано в первом изображении, и как следствие CronCronBundle не найден автозагрузчиком, о чём вам и сообщает ошибка. Убедитесь что все зависимости нужных версий установлены (вместе с расширением ext-filter версии 7.1 и др), либо проведите обновление версий в соответствии с текущей версией ext-filter.